# What resistor rating is this?

Tags: resistors

I can't figure out what rating this is. Can anyone help? I wasn't aware you could have a gold third band when you have a 5 band resistor. [image]

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the color bands are not charred beyond recognition, the bands are:

grey-red-gold-gold-black.

And while there are 5 color bands, it's not a 5-band resistor, it's special.

8.2 ohms 5%, and the special black band can mean many things.

It may mean temperature coefficient, failure rate, fusible resistor, non-inductive or literally anything the manufacturer wanted.

Depending on what the resistor does in the circuit, it might be determined what it means.

If you are unsure what the resistor does in the circuit or what the extra black band means, don't replace it, leave it to an expert. Using the wrong type of resistor may be a fire or other safety hazard.

Also resistors don't simply burn up themselves. A resistor burning up is not the fault itself, s a symptom of a fault elsewhere. There must have been some fault, and there may still be. Unless the fault is fixed, the new resistor will also burn up.

Comment: I see an inrush current limiter directly beside it, and a bridge rectifier nearby -- IMO this is almost certainly a power circuit using this resistor as a fuse.

Answer (score 4):

The black band on the end cap appears on the right hand side of many resistors. It has no apparent meaning other than to identify the right-hand side of the resistor (I could be wrong on that point). I have seen it on many resistors from Asian factories, including some that we purchased directly from the manufacturer in Taiwan.

This appears to be a fusible 8.2Ω 5% resistor, that has already performed the fusible part of its life cycle. Wattage rating should be possible to determine from the dimensions and comparing with other offerings at a distributor.

Chances are something else has rung down the curtain and joined the choir invisible to cause the resistor to fuse. Maybe a switchmode power supply chip or a discrete high-voltage MOSFET has bit the dust. Sometimes a MOV (likely that black disk nearby) buys the farm and causes this to happen, if it's after the resistor.

Answer (score 2):

It's a 5% resistor.  I'm a bit color-blind, so *assuming* that the first two bands are grey and red, it's a \$8.2\Omega\$ resistor, and the final band probably denotes a 250ppm/K temperature coefficient -- but it might mean anything the manufacturer wanted.

It's poorly done -- the temperature coefficient band should have a *distinctly bigger* gap between it and the other four than between any two of the four.  Fortunately, the third band being gold makes it clear that it's not a 3-digit resistance.

From [this page](https://eepower.com/resistor-guide/resistor-standards-and-codes/resistor-color-code/#):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is an 8.2 ohm ± 5% wirewound resistor marked using a 4-band colour code. The extra fifth (black) band marks that this is a wirewound resistor. Note that in the standard resistor colour code, neither black nor white are valid tolerance specifiers.

This resistor may be acting as a fusible resistor and should only be replaced with a similar fusible resistor. It is intended to burn out and is likely burnt out because of a fault elsewhere in your device.